# Как сделать интерактивное расписание?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Как сделать так что бы отображался только один день недели, и по нажатию менялся на другой?
[image: пример]
[код](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R083.png)

Comment: код https://codepen.io/konstantin-zhewzhik/pen/eYOEyVy?editors=1000

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981934/javascript-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-css/982073#982073 - 1-й пример. И так будет работать, но можно бы заменить `getElementsByClassName('link')` на `querySelectorAll('.link')`

Comment: обычные табы, как вариант - https://jqueryui.com/tabs/